# How to calculate the operator norm of sequence-type $T$ e.g. $T: \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis

How to calculate the operator norm of sequence-type $T$ e.g. $T: \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$?

I know that the operator norm def is

$$\|A\|_{op}=\sup_{\|x\|_E \leq 1} \|Tx\|_F$$

If I e.g. have $T: (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \rightarrow \bigg( \frac{x_n}{2n}\bigg)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

Comment: @user657324 Nevermind I noticed my error.

Answer (score 3):

$\|T(x_n)\|^{2}=\sum \frac {|x_n|^{2}} {4n^{2}} \leq \frac 1 4\|x_n\|^{2} $. Hence $\|T\|\leq \frac 1 2$. Now let $e_1=(1,0,...0)$. Then $Te_1=(\frac 1 2,0,...)$ so $\|Te_1\|=\frac 1 2$ and $\|e_1\|=1$. Hence $\|T\| \geq \frac 1 2$ proving that $\|T\|=\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Very smart ! (+1)

Comment: What's the latter part about?

Comment: @mavavilj By definition of the norm of $T$ if we find one vector $x$ of norm $1$ such that $\|Tx\| =\frac 1 2$ then $\|T\| \geq \frac 1 2$. (supremum of any set is greater than or equal to each element of the set).

Comment: But what's the operator norm then? Now you claim that it's $\|T\| \leq 1/2$ and $\|T\T \geq 1/2$, which is contradictory. Is it then $\|T\| = 1/2$?

Comment: They are not contradictory; if $\|T\| \leq \frac 1 2$ and $\|T\| \geq \frac 1 2$ then $\|T\| = \frac 1 2$. @mavavilj